# Open multiple instances of same controller with different data

Tags: angularjs, singleton, angular-ui-router, angular-controller

I have an angular app that allows the users to open details about a product on a modal window. The modal has corresponding url with it (/product/:id). A requirement of the app is that the users should be able to open multiple modals of this state on top of each other - for the different products they are viewing. Ex: /product/1, /product/2... Here is the code for the routing:

```
$stateProvider.state('product', {
url: '/product/:id',
onEnter: ["$modal", function ($modal) {
   $modal.open({
      templateUrl: '/App/product/product.html',
      controller: 'ProductController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
   });
}]
```

});

The problem  is that when I open new modal for a product, all the other previously opened modals of this state re-run their ProductController with the data from the latest product.
How can I run different instances of one controller in parallel, each containing the data for the product that is was opened for?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a resolve object wich would inject the required data from your current scope:

```
$stateProvider.state('product', {
url: '/product/:id',
onEnter: ["$modal", function ($modal) {
   $modal.open({
      templateUrl: '/App/product/product.html',
      controller: 'ProductController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      resolve: {
                            product: function () {
                                $scope.current_roduct= $scope.selected;
                                return $scope.current_roduct;
                            }
                        }
   });
}]             
});
```